# Как удалять сообщения через время

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

У меня есть бот в телеге, я хочу сделать так, чтобы при прописывании определённой команды(пока что /test) выписывалось сообщение(так же тест) и удалялось через пять секунд. Как это сделать?
Бесполезный код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['test', 'Test'])
def send_test(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "тест")
```

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage

Answer (score -1):

Возможно тебе придётся использовать потоки, т.к. это единственная идея которая пришла мне в голову. Пример будет с ошибкам, я уверен, так что вам нужно будет подправить. Например:

```
import time
@bot.message_handler(commands=['test', 'Test'])
def Thread1():
    def send_test(message):
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "тест")
        time.wait(5)
def Thread2():
    другой код, который не должен стопится на 5 сек.
```

Возможно работать так не будет, но я попытался